# Import macros programmatically in Word document

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-word

I am trying to automate the process of importing macros in Word documents, but I fail to load macros in any macro-enabled word document. It works just for the Normal.dotm

I want to create a new doc, and load the macro from a .bas file.

```
$basPath = "C:\Files\macro.bas"
$docPath = "C:\Files\macro_document.doc"

$word = New-Object -ComObject "Word.Application"
$document = $word.documents.Add()
$document.SaveAs($docPath)

$document.VBProject.VBComponents.Import($basPath)

$document.Save()
$document.Close()
$word.Quit()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked your settings in Word's Trust Center -> Macro Settings and insure that "Trust access to the VBA proiect model" is checked. Also are you creating the new document in a Trusted Location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.SaveAs($docPath,0)` where 0 is `wdFormatDocument 97-2003`

```powershell
$basPath = "C:\Files\macro.bas"
$docPath = "C:\Files\macro_document.doc"

$word = New-Object -ComObject "Word.Application"
$document = $word.Documents.Add()
$document.VBProject.VBComponents.Import($basPath)
$document.SaveAs($docPath,0) # 0 = wdFormatDocument 97-2003
$document.Close()
$word.Quit()
```

Or use extension `.docm` and `.SaveAs($docPath,13)` where 13 is `wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled`:

```powershell
$basPath = "C:\Files\macro.bas"
$docPath = "C:\Files\macro_document.docm"

$word = New-Object -ComObject "Word.Application"
$document = $word.Documents.Add()
$document.VBProject.VBComponents.Import($basPath)
$document.SaveAs($docPath,13) # 13 = wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled
$document.Close()
$word.Quit()
```